# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

i need to get echo value i.e (yes or no) from php  file to myresulttextview but unable to retrieve it says error :**"com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. "**

```
val barcode = data.getParcelableExtra<Barcode>(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject)
                        val p = barcode.cornerPoints
                        var m = barcode.displayValue.toString().trim()
                        val jsonobj=JSONObject()
                        jsonobj.put("email",m)
                        val url="https://192.168.2.11/verf1.php"
                        val que=Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
                        val req=JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,jsonobj,Response.Listener {
                            response ->mResultTextView.setText(response.toString())


                        },Response.ErrorListener {
                            response ->mResultTextView.setText(response.toString())

                        })
                        que.add(req)
```

### my php file

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name=false;
if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $user_name = $_POST["email"];
}
$mysql_qry="select *  from exitpass where email like '%".$user_name."%'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
echo"yes";
}
else{
echo"no";}
?>
```

Comment: Is your 192.168.2.11 application forcing HTTPs or can it be served over HTTP.  Try removing the s in HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the TLS/SSL certificate associated with your 192.168.2.11 web server.  There are a few different ways to solve this problem depending on what your setup is like.

If you have no cert installed on your web server then replace https with http to send over an unencrypted channel.

```
 val url="http://192.168.2.11/verf1.php"
```

If the web server does have a cert installed then you could have a few issues. Common issues related to the stack trace are invalid certs, using the wrong (or no) domain name, wrong Java code for the encryption type and Java version, issue somewhere in the trust chain, expired cert, etc.

In summary, I believe you simply need to send over http, but if that doesn't work, you should troubleshoot it in this order.

1. Change the IP to the domain name associated with your cert
2. Verify you can access your resource in the browser and that the certificate is not expired
3. Figure out what type of encryption you are using (TLS 1.1,  TLS 1.2, etc) and what Java you are using (1.6 or 1.7).  There is a key difference between Java 6 and Java 7 as it relates to accessing TLS encrypted resources and I explain it in my highest rated post (as a reference).
4. If all else fails you will likely need to manually install the certificate in Androids JVM trust store. I believe you can do this from most GUIs and definitely from the terminal if you have access.  You shouldn't have to do this, but sometimes you are forced to if the certificate chain breaks.  It might not even be your cert causing the issue, it can be any cert in your trust chain.

Please let me know if the initial suggestion works. If it doesn't work please provide the public cert here ( or just the domain name and I will  pull it down) and your Java version and I can better assist.